# Stuck in solving two variables from two expressions

Tags: equation-solving

After doing experiment with Michelson interferometer I need to calculate two coefficients: *k* and *n*. This involves solving two equations for *k* and *n*:

$$\frac{(8 \pi  d)}{\lambda }{kn}=\frac{\text{$\triangle $I}}{I}$$

$$\text{$\triangle $l}_2=\left\{\frac{\lambda }{2 \pi }\right\} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \left(n \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  d n}{\lambda }\right)+k\right)}{\frac{4 \pi  d \left(n^2-1\right)}{\lambda }+\left(n^2+1\right) \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  d n}{\lambda }\right)}\right)$$

For the first one I have everything exept $\Delta$*r*. As for second one, I have all coefficients. But Mathematica won't solve it neither with *Solve*, neither with *NSolve*.

```
Solve[{k*n==0.00730621, 
1.67/0.00539535==ArcTan[(2(k+n Sin[8.89655n]))/(8.89655(-1+n^2)+(1+n^2)Cos[8.89655 n])]},
 {k,n}]
```

It just goes into ever increasing evaluation till computer starts to freeze or I stop evaluation.

Could anyone suggest how I tackle this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: please put the complete code here.

Comment: Perhaps start by solving the first equation for, say, `n`, plugging that into the second equation, then plotting that equation as a function of `n` and seeing roughly where the roots are. Then use `FindRoot`.

Comment: Thanks for response. 
@RaymondGhaffarianShirazi - it is all the code. I'm just trying to use Mathematica to calculate k,n.

Comment: @march - thanks, for suggestion. I tried it, for function expressed by k, but just got error:
 "The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances."

Which I guess indicates, that this is not the right path to go? I don't know actually. But anyway, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Solve for `k` in terms of `n` and plug the result into the second equation. Then `Plot[ f[n] , {n,-10,10}]` to see that there is no zero. This suggests that there is something strange with the parameter numbers calculated before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following March's suggestion, if one takes the first expression we can determine that `k` is:

```
0.00730621/n
```

Create a function of `n` that represents the second equation. Replace `k` in the second equation with the above expression:

```
eq2[n_] := 1.67/0.00539535 - ArcTan[(2 (0.00730621/n + n Sin[8.89655 n]))/
   (8.89655 (-1 + n^2) + (1 + n^2) Cos[8.89655 n])]
```

Plot it as a function of `n`. Since the equation has `8.89655 n` as an argument to `Sin` and `Cos` it makes sense to limit `n` to be less than `8.89655/(2 π)`.

There is a discontinuity where the denominator goes to zero so it is excluded from the plot.

```
Plot[eq2[n], {n, 0, 8.89655/ (2 π)},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-1.8, 1.8}}, 
 Exclusions -> {(8.89655 (-1 + n^2) + (1 + n^2) Cos[8.89655 n]) == 0}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The plot shows that eq2 never approaches zero. At the discontinuity the `ArcTan` jumps from `-π/2` to `π/2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JackLaVigne 
I just don't understand why you dont use LHS of second equation.

Comment: @JustasJ - Terribly sorry. 100% error on my part. The equation should be modified as shown by Willinski below. Following his and Kagaratsch's comment, it is clear that there is no solution.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for going through all the trouble! @JackLaVigne

Answer (score 0):

There are no zeros (see @Kagaratsch comment).

```
n = 0.00730621/k;
eq = 1.67/0.00539535 - ArcTan[(2 (k +n Sin[8.89655 n]))/(8.89655 (-1 + n^2) + (1 + n^2) Cos[8.89655 n])] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
Plot[eq, {k, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]